# How do I identify that I am at the last byte of a serialized Java object?

Tags: java, serialization

**Question**

What is (if there is any) terminating characters/byte sequences in serialized java objects?

**Background**

I'm working on a small self-education project where I would like to serialize java objects and write them to a stream where there are read and then unserialized. Since, I will need to identify the borders between serialized objects and I can't be sure that the current object is not the last one, is there a terminating character that is always there that I can use as my identifier?

I noticed that there is a magic number ACED that allows me to identify the start of the object, so how do I identify the end?

EDIT:
If there is no terminating character, is there any *safe* terminating characters/sequences that I can use (insert) to identify the end of the object?

Comment: The byte after the current one doesn't exist? :P

Comment: @Lou Since the stream could be a network stream and we could be blocking somewhere. So, "not existing" should work only if we have reached the end of the stream.

Comment: Lou: The byte after the end of an object will be the first byte of the next object.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you should always be able to find the end of an object, in practice you cannot. I understand the problem is customised `writeObject` implementations that don't call either `defaultReadObject` or `readFields` have a non-standard representation.

I've played about with serialisation in the past. Including creating streams for use when I've been doing unusual things to the `ObjectInputStream`. It's not pleasant(!).

You can read the details in the [spec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html), and the source is worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

there are none. AFAIK the only requirement is that the deserialiser know when to stop reading, when given a corresponding serialisation. subject to that, the serialiser can write whatever it wants -- in any position not just the last.

if you're old skool dump a 32-bit length field at the beginning a refuse to handle objects bigger than 4 gig.

nu scool, you just make sure your read and your write logic are consistent and don't care about the length.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a terminating object to your object stream. e.g. null or a special String.

However, I suggest that you instead convert the ObjectsStream to a byte[] and write the byte length of the byte[] followed by its data.  This way each ObjectStream is independent and you always know where it finishes.

Comment: how can you distinguish between the byte length and the real data since they exist on the same array?

Comment: @foobar You always put the length first, then you know the length is at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered applying a record-marking layer similar to [HTTP Chunked encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1)?

The Chunked encoding is intended to solve a generalization of this scenario: identifying the end of a message of indeterminate length that both itself contains no identifiable end, and is embedded in a longer stream without ending it.